# Can't get Data from DHT Sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, grovepi+

**HEy guys,
actually i'm working on a watering system fpor my school.
after i've tried to make a gui with tkinter, what surprisingly was working. After a time i got problems with my DHT Sensor from grovepi.**

the error:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 t.py ^CTraceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grovepi-1.4.1-py3.7.egg/grovepi.py",
> line 227, in read_i2c_block   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Dexter_AutoDetection_and_I2C_Mutex-0.0.0-py3.7.egg/di_i2c.py",
> line 373, in read_list   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Dexter_AutoDetection_and_I2C_Mutex-0.0.0-py3.7.egg/di_i2c.py",
> line 129, in transfer   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Dexter_AutoDetection_and_I2C_Mutex-0.0.0-py3.7.egg/di_mutex.py",
> line 48, in acquire KeyboardInterrupt
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "t.py", line 5, in 
> [temp,hum] = grovepi.dht(dht_sensor, 0)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grovepi-1.4.1-py3.7.egg/grovepi.py",
> line 335, in dht   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grovepi-1.4.1-py3.7.egg/grovepi.py",
> line 242, in read_identified_i2c_block   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grovepi-1.4.1-py3.7.egg/grovepi.py",
> line 232, in read_i2c_block KeyboardInterrupt

My code:

```
import grovepi

dht_sensor = 5

[temp,hum] = grovepi.dht(dht_sensor, 0)

print(temp)
```

**even in this tiny code that happens...
thats the incomplete code:**

```
import time
import datetime
import grovepi
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import threading
import sys
import math


#############################################################
#definition global variables
global str_temp
global str_hum
global str_moist
global thresh
global watered
global stop_thread
global button_status

#############################################################
#define  some start values

thresh = 300
stop_thread = True
watered = False

#############################################################
#connect senosrs/actors

#connect grove LEDS to digital ports (green=7), (red=8)
green = 7
red = 8

#connect button tu digital port D2
button = 2
button_status = grovepi.digitalRead(button)

#connect relay to digital port D3
relay = 3

#connect dht sensor(temperature and humidity) to digital port D4
dht_sensor = 4

#connect moisture sensor to analog port A1
moisture = 1

#############################################################
#define pin modes
grovepi.pinMode(green, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(red, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(relay, "OUTPUT")
grovepi.pinMode(button, "INPUT")

#############################################################
#define functions

def on_closing():
    
    close_gui = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Diplomarbeit Stanislav Shubenok", "Programm beenden?")
    
    
    if close_gui == "yes":
        grovepi.digitalWrite(relay, 0)
        grovepi.digitalWrite(green, 0)
        grovepi.digitalWrite(red, 0)
        root.destroy()
    else:
        return

#############################################################

def green():
    grovepi.digitalWrite(green, 1)

def red():
    grovepi.digitalWrite(red, 1)

#############################################################

def emergency_stop():
    while True:
        button_status = grovepi.digitalRead(button)

        if button__status == 0:
            continue
        else:
            
            grovepi.digitalWrite(relay, 0)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(green, 0)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(red, 0)
            root.destroy()

#############################################################

def stop_thread():
    global stop_thread
    stop_thread = False
def reset_stop_thread():
    global stop_thread
    stop_thread = True

#############################################################

def automatic():
    return

#############################################################

def getdata():
    stop_thread()
    reset_stop_thread()

    underlabel.config(text="Daten werden jede Sekunde aktualisiert")
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        if not stop_thread:
            break
        else:
            [temp,hum] = grovepi.dht(dht_sensor, 0)
            mosit = grovepi.analogRead(moisture)
            str_temp = str(temp)
            str_hum = str(hum)
            str_moist = str(moist)

            named_tuple = time.localtime()
            time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M")
            second = tim.time()
            local_time = time.ctime(second)

            middleLabel1.config(text=str_temp)
            middelLabel2.config(text=str_hum)
            middleLabel3.config(text=str_moist)
            upperLabel.config(text=local_time)
            underLabel.config(text="")
            time.sleep(1)
            
#############################################################

def manually():
    stop_thread()
    moist = grovepi.analogRead(moisture)
    if (moist > thresh):
        grovepi.digitalWrite(relay, 0)
        
        underLabel.config(text="die Erde ist noch feucht")
        reset_stop_thread()
        time.sleep(3)
        
        threadin.Thread(target=getdata).start()
    else:
        underLabel.config(text="es wird 5 Sekunden lang bewässert")
        grovepi.digitalWrite(relay, 1)
        time.sleep(5)
        grovepi.digitalWrite(relay, 0)
        underLabel.config(text="Bewässerung beendet")
        reset_stop_thread()
        time.sleep(2)
        threading.Thread(target=getdata).start()

#############################################################

def read_button():
    while True:
        button_status = grovepi.digitalRead(button)
        if button_status == 0:
            print("nicht gedrückt")
        else:
            print("gedrückt")

#############################################################

#--------------------------main programm-------------------

   

root= tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Diplomarbeit Stanislav Shubenok")
root.config(background="#C4C4C4")
#root.attribute('-zoomed')
root.geometry("400x400")

outerFrame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="#000000", pady=10, padx=5)
outerFrame.pack(pady=1, padx=1)

mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(outerFrame, bg="#FFFFFF", pady=10, padx=5)
mainFrame.pack(pady=1, padx=1)
upperLabel = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text=local_time, bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
upperLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=5)
underLabel = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text="Infos Hier", bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
underLabel.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=5)

leftLabel1 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text="Temperatur:", bg="#FFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
leftLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
leftLabel2 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text="Luftfeuchtigkeit:", bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
leftLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
leftLabel3 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text="Erdfeuchtigkeit", bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
leftLabel3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)

middleLabel1 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text=str_temp, bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
middleLabel1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=5)
middleLabel2 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text=str_hum, bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
middleLabel2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=5)
middleLabel3 = tkinter.Label(mainFrame, text=str_moist, bg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial', '20'))
middleLabel3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=5)

B_getdata = tkinter.Button(mainFrame, text="Daten aktualisieren", bg="#FFFF00", width=15, font=('Arial', '20'), command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=getdata).start())
B_getdata.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=5)
B_automatic = tkinter.Button(mainFrame, text="Automatisch", bg="#00FF00", width=15, font=('Arial', '20'), command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=automatic).start())
B_automatic.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10, padx=5)
B_manually = tkinter.Button(mainFrame, text="Manuell", bg="#0088FF", width=15, font=('Arial', '20'), command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=manually).start())
B_manually.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=5)

threading.Thread(target=getdata).start()


root.protocol("WM_DEKETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
sys.exit("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten, das Programm wurde geschlossen.")
```

**I'm a beginner in programming and need heeelp :(**

Answer (score 1):

Changed Grovepi Bus:

grovepi.set_bus("RPI_1")

works now, eve if it worked before without bus changing.

I think it was the interference of the threads. Multiple Threads trying to read/write Data on the same sensor.

I managed that so it's  not opening multiple threads for that particular case of reading and showing data.

Can be closed